# Show the page with particular item in RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, radgrid

I have a `RadGrid` that I supply with data using `DataSourceID`. The RadGrid has paging, and I want to show the page containing some particular item. To do this, I find the offset of the item in the data and set the page number:

```
var index = dataSource.Count(t => t.Id > _selectedTickId);
var page = index / rgTicks.PageSize;
rgTicks.CurrentPageIndex = page;
```

My question is where to put this code. In the `OnDataBound` I don't seem to have access to the data source. If I put it in the `OnSelecting` the retrieving of data has a side effect of setting the page number. Should I extend the GridTableView to implement this functionality? Which method should I override?

Comment: My approach seems to be wrong. For the grid to display a specific page, it needs to request that page from the data source. It is impossible to let the page number depend on the data source, because the data source already depends on the page number.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to compute `index` value in `OnSelecting` (which is data dependent) while page index can be set in `OnDataBound` or `PreRender` event.

Comment: This makes sense. OnSelecting is for getting the data, and the `index` value is part of the data. It did not solve my problem, but made me realize that I had the wrong approach altogether.

Answer (score 1):

My usecase was to jump to an item that was just inserted using a popup editor. Here's how I solved it. I am omitting non relevant properties in the tag. All the data wiring is up to you, but here are the relevant bits. Important: use DataKeyNames to avoid messy digging in the GridDataItem for a value.

In the page I have:

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="rgItems" runat="server" AllowPaging="true"
       OnNeedDataSource="rgItems_NeedDataSource"
       OnPreRender="rgItems_PreRender"
       OnInsertCommand="rgItems_InsertCommand">
       <MasterTableView
           CommandItemDisplay="Top"
           CommandItemSettings-AddNewRecordText="Add New Item"
           CommandItemSettings-ShowAddNewRecordButton="True"
           DataKeyNames="IntItemId"
           EditMode="popup"
           EditFormSettings-PopUpSettings-Modal="true">
```

And in code behind:

```
private bool itemInserted = false;

protected void rgItems_InsertCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    itemInserted = true;
}

protected void rgItems_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (itemInserted)
    {
        // Select the record and set the page
        int LastItem = 0; // Put code to get last inserted item here
        int Pagecount = rgItems.MasterTableView.PageCount;
        int i = 0;
        GridDataItem GDI = null;
        while (i < Pagecount)
        {
            rgItems.CurrentPageIndex = i;
            rgItems.Rebind();
            GDI = rgItems.MasterTableView.FindItemByKeyValue("IntItemId", LastItem);
            if (GDI != null) break; // IMPORTANT: Breaking here if the item is found stops you on the page the item is on
            i++;
        }
        if (GDI != null) GDI.Selected = true; // Optional: Select the item
        itemInserted = false;
    }
}
```